# Webapp development - native look and feel framework?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, web-applications

I have made some webapps with jQuery Mobile/Phonegap a year ago. Now starting another one. But it seems jQuery Mobile almost didn't advance. Things like:

- Newer UI concepts aren't there. E.g. a left navigation that opens if you click the icon, can make it in jqm, but not very easy.
- The styling in line with iOS7+ and android, jqm seems so 2010 on their styling. It just doesn't look like a (near) native app at all.
- More recent frameworks like Knockout.js and Require.js can be used, but there's so much overlap with jqm.

I looked around, but it seems all good posts on webapps are 2012. Did development somehow stop at that time? I have found the following solutions:

- Sencha Touch: looks good, but goes away from html development, I worry about learning curve. It's almost like native development?
- Dojo Mobile: looks like iPhone 3.
- Cappuccino: focuses on desktop.
- No framework, make html from scratch.

My question: did people give up on webapps for mobile phones with phonegap or are there any good frameworks I don't know about yet?

Comment: Have a look at Twitter Bootstrap, a widely used HTML, CSS, and JS framework. Since version 3 it is mobile first. From the docs at getbootstrap.com: In fact, Bootstrap is mobile first. Mobile first styles can be found throughout the entire library instead of in separate files.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous UI frameworks trying to mimic the native look-and-feel. Take a look at for example:

- [Onsen UI](http://onsenui.io/)
- [AppGyver Steroids](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids)
- [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/)
- [Telerik for PhoneGap](http://www.telerik.com/phonegap-ui)

Also Bootstrap has several themes mimicking native iOS and Android.